# Pyinstaller -w exe still opening terminals in Windows

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, subprocess, pyinstaller

I ran this command to convert my script from .py to .exe:

`pyinstaller.exe -w -i .\icon.png --add-data='icon.png;.' .\gui_script.py`

and after adding in some poorly added packages the GUI opens via my tkinter script. But when I run code using the tkinter window in Windows, every time there's a subprocess.run or os.system function it opens up a new terminal window. Is there any way to suppress these? Or at least make them minimized or not noticeable?

Here's a piece of the gui_script.py that combines two files which opens an external terminal window.

```
import os

os.system('copy cDNA.fa+ncRNA.fa transcriptome.fa /b')
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], otherwise there is far too little information to be able to give an answer.

Comment: Did you try to add **--noconsole** argument?

Comment: `pyinstaller` can't supress `subprocess.run` or `os.system` - it is not its task. It supress only main terminal which is used to start `script.py`. If you use it to start other Python script then use `import` instead `subprocess`.

Comment: The `-w` is synonymous with `--windowed` or `--noconsole` so `-w` should be sufficient. What do you mean by using `import` instead of `subprocess`?

Comment: Don't use `os.system()` if you want fine-grained control of whether the program you're running starts in a window; use `subprocess.Popen` instead, which lets you pass `startupinfo`, optionally with `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`.

Comment: pyinstaller's options only control whether _your Python program itself_ runs in a window, not whether other programs that your Python program starts starts do.

Comment: (also, using `os.system()` has serious security problems if you use variables to fill out your filenames; look up "shell injection")

Comment: Anyhow, there's no good reason to use the `copy` command from Python in the first place. Use `shutil.copyfile()` and you'll have better portability, better error reporting, none of the aforementioned security problems, etc.

Comment: BTW, this should probably be tagged in a way that makes it clear it's a Microsoft Windows problem. On sane, UNIXy platforms, command-line applications don't try to start their own terminals; this problem is exclusively a Windows thing. (No, pyinstaller doesn't imply Windows -- it supports other platforms as well).

Answer (score 1):

I started using python tools for the merging of files:

```
with open('transcriptome.fa','wb') as transcriptome_file:
        for fasta_file in ['cDNA.fa','ncRNA.fa']:
            with open(fasta_file,'rb') as current_fasta:
                shutil.copyfileobj(current_fasta, transcriptome_file)
```

as well as downloading of larger files:

```
with requests.get('http://ftp.ensembl.org/pub/current_fasta/'+species+'/cdna/'+cDNA_file_name, stream=True) as cDNA_request:
        with open('cDNA.fa.gz', 'wb') as cDNA_gz_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(cDNA_request.raw, cDNA_gz_file)
```

Despite this I still need to run an external program, blast, so there I used subprocess.run with the creationflag = subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW argument like this:

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    blast_db_run = subprocess.run(['makeblastdb',
                            '-in', fasta_file,
                            '-dbtype', 'nucl',
                            '-out','blast_db'],
                            capture_output=True, 
                            creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)
```

Used the if statement since creationflags doesn't work in a non-windows environment apparently.